# Map Variable Feature In Google Forms

Tags: forms, google-forms, google-workspace

Does Google Forms have an option where I can ask a student a question and they can respond by moving a variable on a designated & titled X/Y axis? I would like to have a 2D model where participants can respond to the question by individually placing their markers. Is this possible? Is this possible on another metric, like Qualtrics?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the meaning of `respond by moving a variable on a designated & titled X/Y axis?` You can have a question where a student can input their response to a question requiring an X and Y value; but if you are thinking about a dynamic response, then this is not a feature of Google Forms.